# ASP.NET GridView Save Data to Database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a `grid` for TimeTable entries.
 The column list goes like this.

```
S.No  Slot Name  Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
====  =========  ======= =======  =========  ========  ========
```

Column **Slot Name** has values already loaded from the database.

A user can enter data for any day, under any period i.e., Time Slot.(The user can add data from a popup which appears from click of add button inside each column).

In case the user does not enter for any day, the data should not be saved to the database. How do I check this?

P.S. Save operation in this page saves data first to a parent table which has information like School, Class, term, Section etc., After this is saved, the individual details for each day are saved to another table.

---

@Syed, here's my code for insert.

```
Dim sFacultyLabelDetail As String = "lbl" & sDay & "Faculty"
Dim lblFacNameDetail As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = row.FindControl(sFacultyLabel)

Dim sSubjectLabelDetail As String = "lbl" & sDay & "Subject"
Dim lblSubjectNameDetail As System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label = row.FindControl(sSubjectLabel)

dsGetTimeTableDetailID = (From t1 In dbl.TimeTableDetails Where t1.TimeTableBreakUpID = dsSaveTimeTableBreakUpDetails And t1.Date = stDate Select t1.TimeTableDetailID).FirstOrDefault.ToString

If (dsGetTimeTableDetailID = 0 And (Trim(lblSubjectNameDetail.Text) <> "" Or Trim(lblFacNameDetail.Text) <> "" Or Trim(lblIsExternal.Text) <> "")) Then
    dsSaveTimeTableDetailsForView = dbl.usp_InsertTimeTableDetailsForViewTimeTable(0, dsSaveTimeTableBreakUpDetails, Val(lblFacID.Text), Trim(lblFacNameDetail.Text), Val(lblSubjectID.Text), Trim(lblSubjectNameDetail.Text), stDate.Date, Trim(lblIsExternal.Text), sDayName, "Y", sUserName, DateTime.Now).ReturnValue
ElseIf (dsGetTimeTableDetailID <> 0) And (Trim(lblSubjectNameDetail.Text) = "" And (Trim(lblFacNameDetail.Text) = "" And Trim(lblIsExternal.Text) = "")) Then
    dsSaveTimeTableDetailsForView = dbl.usp_UpdateTimeTableDetailsForViewTimeTable(dsGetTimeTableDetailID, dsSaveTimeTableBreakUpDetails, Val(lblFacID.Text), Trim(lblFacNameDetail.Text), Val(lblSubjectID.Text), Trim(lblSubjectNameDetail.Text), stDate.Date, Trim(lblIsExternal.Text), sDayName, "N", sUserName, DateTime.Now).ReturnValue
ElseIf (dsGetTimeTableDetailID <> 0 And (Trim(lblSubjectNameDetail.Text) <> "" Or Trim(lblFacNameDetail.Text) <> "" Or Trim(lblIsExternal.Text) <> "")) Then
    dsSaveTimeTableDetailsForView = dbl.usp_UpdateTimeTableDetailsForViewTimeTable(dsGetTimeTableDetailID, dsSaveTimeTableBreakUpDetails, Val(lblFacID.Text), Trim(lblFacNameDetail.Text), Val(lblSubjectID.Text), Trim(lblSubjectNameDetail.Text), stDate.Date, Trim(lblIsExternal.Text), sDayName, "Y", sUserName, DateTime.Now).ReturnValue    
End If
```

Here **sDay** is the header name from the grid(Monday/Tuesday...)

Comment: What do you mean by how to check? Do you want to check it on your end or you want to display it grid or whatever?

Comment: I need to check whether all the labels in the grid are empty. In that case, I should not allow to save.

Comment: means you want to validate the grid? if fields are empty then you dont want to save the data isnt so?

Comment: post the code of insertion.